# M2E Get Order Info programmatically

Tags: orders, tax, m2e

Normally I would get a Magento order info (like Tax) in this way:

`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($set['order_id']);
echo $order->getShippingTaxAmount();`

But for Ebay orders I am not able to see the M2E Order Information in the Order Object, specifically the Tax.

In the Admin area I need to click on "Show Ebay Order" to see the Tax, but i need to write a report that needs this value. Does anyone know how to retrieve the M2E Ebay Order information programmatically?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

this is what I needed:

```
$ebay_order = Mage::getModel('M2ePro/Ebay_Order')->load('41289'); 
$tax = $ebay_order->getTaxDetails();
```

**UPDATE 2**

For those in cases where you only have the `increment_id` for the Magento Order. You will need retrieve the ChannelOrderId first then filter the collection by `ebay_order_id`

See my example below:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);

$paymentInfo = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true);
$channelOrderId = $paymentInfo->getChannelOrderId();

$ebay_order = Mage::getModel('M2ePro/ebay_order')->getCollection()
          ->addFieldToFilter('ebay_order_id', $channelOrderId)
          ->getFirstItem();

$tax = $ebay_order->getTaxDetails();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ebay_order);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($tax);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to load orders based on the marketplace, i.e. `$order = Mage::getModel('M2ePro/Ebay_Order')->load($id); $tax = $order->getTaxDetails();` as given in `Ess_M2ePro_Model_Ebay_Order` (or `$order = Mage::getModel('M2ePro/Amazon_Order')->load($id);` per `Ess_M2ePro_Model_Amazon_Order`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just for the record as it was resolved in the comments already - and furthermore to provide some ideas on how one can approach a situation like the questioner.

Unlike the name of the class `Ess_M2ePro_Model_Order` may let one assume, it does not provide any relevant information on externally placed orders.

The relevant class seems to be `Ess_M2ePro_Model_Ebay_Order` for Ebay- and `Ess_M2ePro_Model_Amazon_Order` for Amazon-orders. In both the method `getTaxDetails()` can be found.

A practical example would be:

```
$id = 1; // order id of interest
$order = Mage::getModel('M2ePro/Ebay_Order')->load($id); // load the order
$tax = $order->getTaxDetails(); // get tax details from order
/**
 * Note: Since I haven't worked with this module yet and haven't been
 * able to find any dummy/demo data I can't tell what the returned array
 * looks like exactly, yet, based on other methods in class it seems to
 * hold at least the keys 'rate' and 'amount'.
 * (@Hector, maybe you could share a var_dump() here?)
 */
```

---

Now just some quick ideas how one can approach a situation like this (assuming that there is not sufficient documentation provided and you don'T want to review every single file):

Especially in modules with a large amount of files/classes/methods it's always worth a shot to first of all check how the initial developer did approach a certain task. Basically this is one common way the check how certain functionality is integrated in Magento core as well when it comes to modifying a certain behavior.
For the given module and problem this means, a quick check on what tables / table columns look promising is always a good starting point (unfortunately, due to the separated install/upgrade scripts in Magento 1 there is mostly hardly a way around of installing a module first, before being able to get the whole table structure).

Since the obvious one (`m2epro_order`) does not hold any column that seems relevant (it just has columns like `account_id`, `marketplace_id`, `store_id`, ...) the class `Ess_M2ePro_Model_Order` got pretty much uninteresting (this assumption was confirmed when having a quick look at the methods in `app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Order.php`). Yet (when you wish to assume that the module creator did a nice job) continuing digging for the obvious mostly leads you to what you're looking for - doing so for this module would certainly bring you to the table `m2epro_ebay_order`. Since this table fits nicely to `Model/Ebay/Order.php` you're pretty much reached your goal already.

Another way to search for something you really expect to be present some where in a given module is to use the (Unix) CLI command `grep -r "searchstring" /path/to/folder`. Running this for some catchy phrases such as `tax_details` (the column name we found earlier), `getTaxDetails` (based on the column name) - or when in doubt `getTax`, `Tax` or `tax` (note that the command is case sensitive - *there might be a way to overcome this but that's even further out of scope than what I'm tying already anyway ;)* ). Next to some other stuff this will eventually come up with

```
C:\laragon\www\mage1936\app\code\community\Ess\M2ePro
λ grep -r "getTax" ./
[...]
./Model/Amazon/Order.php:    public function getTaxDetails()
./Model/Amazon/Order.php:        $taxDetails = $this->getTaxDetails();
./Model/Amazon/Order.php:        $taxDetails = $this->getTaxDetails();
./Model/Amazon/Order.php:        $taxDetails = $this->getTaxDetails();
./Model/Ebay/Order.php:    public function getTaxDetails()
./Model/Ebay/Order.php:    public function getTaxRate()
./Model/Ebay/Order.php:        $taxDetails = $this->getTaxDetails();
./Model/Ebay/Order.php:    public function getTaxAmount()
```

Module source for reference: https://github.com/m2epro/magento1-extension

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Christoph for helping understand the Class in more detail. Per your comment I will share what the returned array looked like for me:

`$order = Mage::getModel('M2ePro/Ebay_Order')->load($id); 
$tax = $order->getTaxDetails();`

`Array
(
    [rate] => 7
    [amount] => 12.11
    [is_vat] => 
    [includes_shipping] => 
)`

And `$order` holds these keys:

`[order_id] => 00000
            [ebay_order_id] => 0000000000
            [selling_manager_id] => 00000
            [buyer_name] => Name
            [buyer_email] => email@yahoo.com
            [buyer_user_id] => user000000
            [buyer_message] => 
            [buyer_tax_id] => 
            [paid_amount] => 0.0000
            [saved_amount] => 0.0000
            [currency] => USD
            [checkout_status] => 1
            [shipping_status] => 2
            [payment_status] => 3
            [shipping_details] => {"address":{"country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","city":"Tampa","state":"FL","postal_code":"000000","phone":"00000","street":["PO Box 0000"],"company":""},"service":"USPS Priority Mail","price":13,"date":"2018-01-30 15:08:10","global_shipping_details":[],"click_and_collect_details":[],"in_store_pickup_details":[],"cash_on_delivery_cost":0}
            [payment_details] => {"date":"2018-01-29 21:53:54","method":"PayPal","status":"NoPaymentFailure","is_refund":false}
            [tax_details] => {"rate":7,"amount":12.11,"is_vat":false,"includes_shipping":false}
            [purchase_update_date] => 2018-02-02 22:39:36
            [purchase_create_date] => 2018-01-29 21:34:41`